# How to test a function which calls many functions... in GTest?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, testcase

I have one function called onStartingExecute();

Which in terms calls many function as below...

```
tt_init_device();
tt_init_port();
tt_init_pipeline();
```

.... and so on....

---

I have written a GTest case as below..

```
TEST_F(ICFusaTelltaleClientAppThTest,Test_onStartingExecute)
{
   FusaTelltaleClientAppTh AppThobj(1,"abc");
   AppThobj.onStartingExecute();
}
```

But my test case is getting failed...

Please help me in how to write test case here...
Am new to GTest...might be it is very simple. :-)

Thanks in advance.!

Comment: the question is unclear. You already wrote a test. It fails, so you have to fix the code, but thats an issue of the code, not of the test.

Comment: Looking just at the headline question, all functions should be covered by unit and functional tests, where you give inputs and ensure that the behavior is expected. Testing a function that happens to call other functions is no different. If the test is failing, and the test appears to be good, then your code doesn't behave the way you expect it to and needs to be fixed. This is why you write tests.

Comment: You haven't specified what you mean by failing. But try adding breakpoints and step through the function to see where it is failing.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear enough, but I guess I can give you some steps to understand the google test:

1. Since your tests fail and you don't know why, so add breakpoints before calling your functions. check your logic that makes the test fail and fix it.
2. If you only expect that your functions have been called with an excepted output use `mock`, so you define a Mock class and add the mocks for each method separately see [gmock](https://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_for_dummies.html) to get started with mocks.

Answer (score 0):

Since the TEST lacks any assertions, https://google.github.io/googletest/reference/assertions.html, I assume you mean you have a compile or runtime error.

The most important thing to include, is verbatim ("word for word") the error message you receive from the computer.
Without this information, you are asking us to assume too much.